# disable temp folder generation in tomcat 6 on restart

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Is it possible to stop generating temp folder on restarting of tomcat 6.0.18?

I have just deleted temp folder from tomcat and restarted server, then it's automatically generate temp folder again, can we stop to generate?